# Does InnoDB Log Files take RAM space or Disk Space

Tags: innodb, database-recommendation, database-tuning, buffer-pool

**When I set InnoDB Log File size to 512M, does it take the space (512M * 2) from RAM or the SSD Disk space?**

When I explored, I can see that the log files are located inside `/var/lib/mysql` folder. So from this I am assuming it is infact stored in disk space and not RAM. I always thought when I allocate log files space it was coming off the RAM and now I have a feeling I was wrong with that assumption. Can someone confirm this please...

Also I am considering to increase the log size to maybe 1GB (for a 3GB Buffer Pool Size) and I am not sure if that would have an effect on my ram usage where I would need to increase my Ram too when I increase the demand for log size. If log files doesnt consume Ram space then I dont see it affecting my ram even if the logfile size are increased. And hence my question to clarify this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB log files are stored on disk and so consume disk space - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html. However the innodb_buffer_pool_size does impact memory usage.

I find this a good reference for memory sizing - http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/

Comment: Thank you clarifying and for the references. And +1 for the mysqlcalculator. That will be helpful. :)